Proof that the derivative of a second order tensor w.r.t. a second order tensor is a fourth order tensor
We know that, since a linear map $T$ from a vector space $V$ to a vector space $W$ can be represented by a matrix, and, the derivative of a vector function $f:V \rightarrow W$ at $a \in V$ is the linear map $D$ for which,
$$
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\left\lvert f(a+h)-f(a)-D h  \right\rvert}{|h|}=0
$$
where $h \in V$ then  $D$ can be  represented by matrix.
$\def\tsr#1#2#3{{{#1}^{#2}}_{#3}}$
$\def\cT{\mathcal{T}}$
$\def\ltsr#1#2#3{{{}^{#2}}_{#3}{#1}}$
$\def\qty#1{\left[ #1 \right]}$
$\def\dF{\mathbb{F}}$
A mixed second-order tensor  is a bilinear map $\ltsr{T}{1}{1}: V^* \times V \rightarrow \dF$ (where $\mathbb{F}$ is the field over which vector space $V$ is defined and $V^*$ is the dual space of $V$), and $\ltsr{\cT(V)}{1}{1}$ is the vector space of mixed second-order tensors. There is more than one candidate for a linear map $D: \ltsr{\cT(V)}{1}{1} \rightarrow \ltsr{\cT(V)}{1}{1}$. We can define a linear map as,
$$
\def\vb#1{\mathbf{#1}}
\def\cC{\mathcal{C}}
Y=D(X) \iff \ltsr{Y}{1}{1} :=\ltsr{\cC}{1}{2} \left(\ltsr{D}{1}{1} \otimes \ltsr{X}{1}{1}\right) \tag{I}\label{I}
$$
($\ltsr{\cC}{i}{j}:\ltsr{\cT(V)}{r}{s}\rightarrow \ltsr{\cT(V)}{r-1}{s-1}$ is the contraction operator that applies the canonical pairing of the $i$th $V^*$ factor and the $j$th $V$ factor). Another way of defining the linear map is,
$$
Y=D(X) \iff
\ltsr{Y}{1}{1} :=  \ltsr{\cC}{2}{2}\left(\ltsr{\cC}{2}{3} \left(\ltsr{D}{2}{2} \otimes \ltsr{X}{1}{1}\right)\right) \tag{II}\label{II}
$$
where $\ltsr{D}{2}{2} \in \ltsr{\cT(V)}{2}{2}$ the vector space of bilinear maps $\ltsr{T}{2}{2}: V^* \times V^* \times V \times V \rightarrow \dF$.
Using heuristics, it is clear that, since we want to relate all components $\tsr{Y}{j}{i}$ to all components $\tsr{X}{k}{l}$, ($\ref{II}$) is the only  linear map that can represent the derivative of $Y$ w.r.t. $X$ (($\ref{I}$) only relates the components of $Y$ that have the same contravariant index as $X$). But is there a rigorous justification for defining the derivative this way?

By derivative I guess you mean a connection, which however is NOT a tensor. Under a given coordinate system it can be represented by 'a tensor' though.

I don't understand what you're trying to do. If you want "the derivative of a second order tensor w.r.t. a second order tensor", just take both $V$ and $W$ in your first paragraph to be ${}^1_1\mathcal T(V)$. Then $D : {}^1_1\mathcal T(V) \to {}^1_1\mathcal T(V)$ is a linear map. End of story. You haven't specified $f$ so it doesn't make sense to talk about "candidates for $D$". Even if you do specify $f$, it still doesn't make sense to talk about "candidates" because $D$ is necessarily unique.
If what you want is to understand how a linear map ${}^1_1\mathcal T(V) \to {}^1_1\mathcal T(V)$ is a fourth-order tensor, then what you need is the following: for any vector spaces $U, V, W$ there are natural isomorphisms
$$
  U\otimes\mathbb F \cong U,\quad U\cong (U^*)^*,
$$$$
  (V\otimes W)^* \cong V^*\otimes W^*,\quad V\otimes W\cong W\otimes V,
$$$$
 U\otimes(V\otimes W) \cong (U\otimes V)\otimes W \cong U\otimes V\otimes W,
$$$$
  \mathrm{Hom}(U\otimes V, W) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(V, U^*\otimes W).
$$
Now noting that naturally an element of ${}^1_1\mathcal T(V)$ can be considered a linear map $V\otimes V^* \to \mathbb F$, a map ${}^1_1\mathcal T(V) \to {}^1_1\mathcal T(V)$ is an element of $\mathrm{Hom}([V\otimes V^*]^*, [V\otimes V^*]^*)$ and so applying the above isomorphisms
$$
  \mathrm{Hom}([V\otimes V^*]^*, [V\otimes V^*]^*) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(V^*\otimes V^{**}, V^*\otimes V^{**}) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(V^*\otimes V, V^*\otimes V) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(V^*\otimes V\otimes V\otimes V^*, \mathbb F) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(V\otimes V\otimes V^*\otimes V^*, \mathbb F).
$$
This final space is naturally the same thing as ${}^2_2\mathcal T(V)$. There is a little bit of choice here, in that we could independently swap the two copies of $V$ or the two copies of $V^*$.

Thanks for the feedback, I will endeavor to improve the wording of the question. In my mind, the derivative of a second order tensor $X$ w.r.t. $X$ is a fourth order tensor $D=\delta^j_i \delta^l_k \mathbf{e}_j \otimes \mathbf{e}_l \otimes e^j \otimes e^k$. By the way you are right , all I am trying to understand is whether the linear map ${}^1_1\mathcal T(V) \to {}^1_1\mathcal T(V)$ is a fourth-order tensor.

@TedBlack Why the deltas? In general it will just have some arbitrary coefficients $D^{jl}{ik}$. To be as concrete as possible, given $D : {}^1_1\mathcal T(V) \to {}^1_1\mathcal T(V)$, you just plugin basis vectors to get the coefficients:　$$D^{jl}{ik} = D(e^j\otimes e_i)(e^l, e_k)$$ where by $e^j\otimes e_i$ I mean the function $(v, \omega) \mapsto e^j(v)\omega(e_i)$ for all $v \in V$ and $\omega \in V^*$.

The deltas are only for the specific case of the derivative of a second order tensor w.r.t. itself ($\partial X / \partial X$). Yes in general it would have some arbitrary coefficients ${D^{jl}}_{ik}$.

You write "${}^1_1\mathcal T(V)$ can be considered a linear map $V\otimes V^* \to \mathbb F$, a map ${}^1_1\mathcal T(V) \to {}^1_1\mathcal T(V)$ is an element of $\mathrm{Hom}([V\otimes V^]^, [V\otimes V^]^)$". How did $\mathrm{Hom}(V\otimes V^, V\otimes V^)$ become $\mathrm{Hom}([V\otimes V^]^, [V\otimes V^]^)$?

@TedBlack It didn't. A linear map $V\otimes V^* \to \mathbb F$ is by definition an element of $[V\otimes V^]^$, so ${}^1_1\mathcal T(V) \cong [V\otimes V^]^$. I'm trying to go step-by-step; saying that ${}^1_1\mathcal T(V) \cong V\otimes V^*$ requires applying the isomorphisms I listed in my answer, which is what I'm doing in the display equation after saying "and so appying the above isomorphisms".

OK I must get a good reference on this, I missed the basic fact that for any vector space, a linear map $\phi: V \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ means $\phi \in V^*$.
