General way to find derivative of tensor operation.
Suppose a domain $D_S\subseteq \mathbb {N}^n$ of dimension $n$ and of shape $S\in\mathbb {N} ^n$ is the index set
$$
D_S=\{(d_0,\ldots,d_{n-1}) \in \mathbb {N_1} \times \ldots \times \mathbb {N_n} \ | \ d_0 \leq S_0,\ldots d_{n-1} \leq S_{n-1}\}.
$$
Now suppose the set of tensors of shape $S$, is the set
$$
T(S)=\{t : D_S \to \mathbb R\}.
$$
Given a shape $S$ of dimension $n$, we can define addition for two $X,Y\in T(S)$ via
$$
Z=X+Y \iff Z_d = X_d+Y_d =Z(d)=X(d)+Y(d) \qquad \forall d\in D_S.
$$
How does one arrive at the definition of $\frac{\partial Z}{\partial X}$ or $\frac{\partial Z}{\partial Y}$? These in particular I know how to compute, but don't understand their derivation. How does one find their shape?
Now suppose that $f:T(S) \to \mathbb R$ and $L = f(Z)=f(X+Y)\in \mathbb R$. Then
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial X}=\frac{\partial f(Z)}{\partial X}=\frac{\partial f(Z)}{\partial Z}\cdot\frac{\partial Z}{\partial X}
$$
and likewise for $Y$. How does one find the sape of $\frac{\partial f(Z)}{\partial Z}$? What is $\cdot$ in this case? Surely it's not element wise product...
I am trying to understand how the derivatives of tensors with respect to other tensors are computed in general. Is there a minimal set of operations for which all operations like this may be defined?

Perhaps this might help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4895365/proof-that-the-derivative-of-a-second-order-tensor-w-r-t-a-second-order-tensor/4904322?noredirect=1#comment10468906_4904322

In this case, since $T(S)$ is a finite dimensional vector space (normed etc), you should understand the derivative of a (not neccesarily linear) map $f:T(S)\to V$ at a point $X\in T(S)$ as a linear map $Df(X):T(S)\to V$. This is the so-called Fréchet derivative. You can also understand it as a Gateaux derivative.
In the first case, the map is of type $T(S)\to T(S)$ and it is given by $X\mapsto X+Y$. In the second one, the map $f$ is of type $T(S)\to \mathbb R$, given by $X\mapsto f(X)$.
